# Transition from R to Python: Where did my levels go?

Tags: python, pandas

if I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'moreLabels': ['D','E','F'], 
'numbers': [1,2,3] })
```

and I want to find out all possible values for 'moreLabels', is there an easy way to do this? I am pivoting and listing the columns of the pivot table like this:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(values = 'numbers', index = 'labels', 
columns = 'moreLabels'
list(pivot.columns)
```

, but this takes several steps and I would like to have a tidy way to do this like

```
dataframe[column].levels()
```

Comment: Please [create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get good responses.

Comment: edited to make an example

Comment: Python doesn't have an exact equivalent because R lists the labels of a factor variable in a levels call. I think you're looking for `.unique()`, though.

Comment: Are you looking for unique values or just all the values in that column?

Comment: @3novak missed your comment - you should post as answer!

Comment: definitely unique values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R's `levels()` function will list all possible values of the variable, even if those values are not present in the data frame. Pandas doesn't behave in this way.

```
> df <- data.table(moreLabels = c('D', 'E', 'F'), numbers = c(1, 2, 3))
> df[, moreLabels := as.factor(moreLabels)]
> df[, levels(moreLabels)]
[1] "D" "E" "F"

> df[numbers > 1, ]  # if we subset, we only see values "E" and "F"
   moreLabels numbers
1:          E       2
2:          F       3

> df[numbers > 1, levels(moreLabels)]
[1] "D" "E" "F"  # even though we would expect only "E" and "F"
```

If you are looking for unique values that appear in the column, use the [pd.Series.unique()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) function.

```
>>> df['moreLabels'].unique()
['D', 'E', 'F']
```